# Use mock library to test a constructor behaviour in an abstract class without creating the derived class directly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, nunit, moq

My requirements say that every type which derives from my abstract base class must contain at least one field with the specified type. This type must implement my interface. (To simplify the example I assume there can be only one child class in the inheritance chain.) I can test this requirement by creating simply fake class directly in the test class (see example below).

```
  public interface ISampleInterface
  {
  }

  public class SampleClass : ISampleInterface
  {
  }

  public abstract class BaseClass
  {
    public BaseClass()
    {
      // try to get fields of ISampleInterface type
      var fields = GetType().GetFields();
      var sampleInterfaceFields = fields.Where(f => typeof(ISampleInterface).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType));
      if (!sampleInterfaceFields.Any())
        throw new MissingFieldException($"Derived class must contain at least one type which implements {nameof(ISampleInterface)}!");
    }
  }

  [TestFixture]
  public class BaseClassTests
  {
    public class FakeDerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
      //public SampleClass sampleClass; //this field is required to properly create the object
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldConstructorThownExceptionWhenDerivedClassDoesNotContainRequiredFields()
    {
      var exception = Assert.Throws<MissingFieldException>(() => new FakeDerivedClass());
      StringAssert.Contains($"Derived class must contain at least one type which implements {nameof(ISampleInterface)}!", exception.Message);
    }
  }
```

I am considering a better approach to test this behaviour by using some mocking library. I prefer Moq, but I am also thinking about NSubstitute. Thanks in advance for any suggestions how to improve this testing code.

Comment: I am really confused as to what this is supposed to do.  Why not just check `if(FakeDerivedClass is ISampleInterface)`  You should be binding your classes to whichever interface

Comment: Why not just create a protected field so that derived classes will all have it.

Comment: That aside you can search the assembly for all classes that derive from the base class and perform your check

Comment: @Nkosi I've corrected my question. I don't want to force the user to use my interface directly for the type of required field.

Comment: @rgb Then why check for and and throw an exception is it is not implemented.

Comment: @Nkosi Because I'd like to force the user to use my interface indirectly. I mean, create the class which implement my interface and use this class as a type of at least one field in class which derived from `BaseClass`. My example is simplified so maybe looks strange at first glance.

Comment: @rgb It is confusing at first glance. Can you provide a clearer version of what it is you are trying to do. 
This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi The current description of the problem should be clear now and I don't want to complicate it more. I can't accept current responses because there aren't solve the problem from my question. The approach with an abstract property force the name of the property and the field type to be a base type. I want to allow the user to choose both type and property name so I check this at runtime instead of compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [abstract property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties) on the base class to ensure that derived classes have at least the one defined on the base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    protected abstract ISampleInterface SampleProperty { get; }

}
```

That way all derived class will have at least implemented the the minimum desired behavior

```
public class SampleClass : ISampleInterface {
    //...
}

public class FakeDerivedClass : BaseClass {
   ISampleInterface sampleField = new SampleClass();

   protected override ISampleInterface SampleProperty {
       get {
           return sampleField;
       }
   }
}
```

There would then be no need to check manually for the desired property as the compiler would provide error details if it was not implemented. No need to re-invent existing behavior that you get out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - you require a class to have an internal field by referencing it and attempting to use it. That way if it's missing your code won't compile. You can write code to check for the existence of an internal field that isn't otherwise used and throw an exception if it's missing, but that wouldn't make any sense.

If a class (base or otherwise) needs to access a field with a given type, for example:

```
public class MyClass
{

    void DoSomethingThatRequiresTheFieldINeed()
    {
        var value = _theField.Value;
    }

    // or

    SomeType PropertyThatExposesTheField => _theField;
}
```

Then writing a line of code that references the field will cause that field to be required. In other words, if, in the above class, I don't add a field called `_theField`, my code won't compile. If a class needs to have a member and doesn't, that should be a compiler error, not a runtime error.

(Technically the field could be in a base class. But in that case I'd make it a property. An inherited class shouldn't be able to mess with the internals of the class it inherits from any more than any other class should be able to. If you're in the family I'll expose a property so you can access my refrigerator, but you can't remove it or replace it with a different refrigerator. My underwear drawer is a private field, and if I want you to access it I'll provide a method.)

If the above solution doesn't work, that means that you're requiring a field to be a in a class whether you need it or not. That's not good. The only reason to ever have a field in a class is because you need it. If you can delete an internal member from a class and it still compiles then what you deleted almost certainly didn't need to be there, requirement or otherwise.

If a class is required to have an externally accessible member then it it should implement an interface. Otherwise there's no way to reference that class and know that it has the given member. We know it has the member because it implements the interface.

> My requirements say that every type which derives from my abstract base class must contain at least one field with the specified type. This type must implement my interface.

If you require an object to be of a type that implements a particular interface then declare it as the type of that interface. That's exactly, precisely what interfaces are for. Or if it's not the interface - you just want it to be a particular type which implements the interface, declare it as that type.

But whatever we require of an object is described in how we use it. If we expect an object to have the properties or methods of `ISomeInterface` then we'll attempt to use them. If the type doesn't implement that interface either directly or by inheritance then our code won't compile.